# How can I access BIOS on an external monitor, when primary display is broken?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, bios, bootloader, defective-hardware

I am basically having the same issue as this ([How to install access BIOS with broken screen](https://superuser.com/questions/1599131/how-to-install-access-bios-with-broken-screen)) with my Sony VAIO VPCEB33FD (Windows 7).

The external monitor only works once Windows starts. I opened up the laptop and disconnected the built-in monitor hoping it would default to the external display, but that didn't change anything.

- I want to access the BIOS so I can change the boot priority so that I can run/install Linux Mint.
- Is there any other way, maybe through Windows, that I can change the boot order, or access the BIOS?
- Are there maybe some terminal commands that can be used to access the BIOS, or change settings?
- Could there be a way to connect an external monitor to the laptop internally, so that it thinks it is the built-in display?

Comment: Put the machine is a Dock, close the lid, and start it. That normally works (done this). It may be cheaper to replace the monitor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing BIOS on laptop with broken screen](https://superuser.com/questions/1311321/accessing-bios-on-laptop-with-broken-screen)

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1311321/accessing-bios-on-laptop-with-broken-screen, https://superuser.com/questions/476933/cannot-enter-bios-due-to-broken-screen, https://superuser.com/questions/476933/cannot-enter-bios-due-to-broken-screen

Comment: See also https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Sony+VAIO+VPCEB33FD+display for replacement, ~US$50 and up.

Comment: I had a similar situation, and I was able to fix it by removing the whole broken display and shorting some pins that made the laptop believe the external display was the primary display. I might put up an answer later.